# dataTables custom filtering of <tr> if class list contains a class

Tags: jquery, filter, datatable, datatables

How can I filter datatable rows by class when the row has multiple classes.  I need for the row to appear in any instance when the class list contains the class I filter for.

```
<tr class="gradeA">...</tr>
<tr class="gradeA gradeC">...</tr>
<tr class="gradeC">...</tr>
```

The row with `"gradeA gradeC"` should appear in both instances.

I've tried using `.nTr.className.split(" ")`, but it is not working as expected.

I've set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/k6seLxkm/). The row with both classes has "1 has BOTH classes" in the first column as a marker to help see if appears in both lists.

http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/k6seLxkm/

Thank you in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in your `if` condition was backwards; you need to return true/false based on if the checked grade is found within the classes of the element. Try this:

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.[afnFiltering][1].push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    var myRowClasses = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.className.split(" ");

    if ($('#ckb-gradeA').is(':checked')) {
        return myRowClasses.indexOf('gradeA') > -1;
    } else if ($('#ckb-gradeC').is(':checked')) {
        return myRowClasses.indexOf('gradeC') > -1;
    }

    return false;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6seLxkm/3/)

Also note that you can make this logic more generic by using classes and `data` attributes on the checkboxes themselves, for example:

```
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="grade-check" data-grade="gradeA" checked="checked" />grade A
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="grade-check" data-grade="gradeB" />grade B
<input type="radio" name="RadioGroup1" class="grade-check" data-grade="gradeC" />grade C
```

```js
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
    var myRowClasses = oSettings.aoData[iDataIndex].nTr.className.split(" ");
    var grade = $('.grade-check:checked').data('grade');    
    return myRowClasses.indexOf(grade) > -1;
});
```

Using this pattern means that the JS will never need to change no matter how many grade checkboxes are added.

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k6seLxkm/4/)

Comment: It seems not to work in ie8.  Do you know what the problem is?